# Theory of complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, complex-integration

I don't know if this is a pedestrian question or not, but here goes. I am working through Ahlfors' complex analysis, which has been a great (and challenging) text to get a grasp of the basics of the subject. However, I am interested in looking into an introduction to a purely complex measure theory and theory of integration that doesn't defer to real integral properties, if nothing else just to satisfy some of my questions.

Can anyone recommend me a source or text to intro this that doesn't involve me being repeatedly slapped in the face by Walter Rudin?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a purely complex measure theory and theory of integration."  In complex variables it is most common to take integrals of complex valued-functions over real intervals; these integrals often have the form $\int_a^b f(\gamma(x))\gamma'(x)\,dx$, where $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$, but they are in no wise different from other integrals.  Tao is said to have a book on measure theory for the Rudin-allergic.

Comment: I tend to think that a fistfight with Walter is an important part of growing up.

Comment: The concept of complex measure will not give you any new definition of contour integral. And eventually some math will slap you in the face.

Comment: So what I am gathering is that there is no purely complex approach to measure theory. I guess that in itself is interesting.